# Reporting / BI Framework for social websites

Tags: reporting, analytics, business-intelligence

I'm looking for ideas / open source frameworks to use for creating individual Analytics for user profiles and all the other profile types. Users will have different custom metrics, businesses willl have seperate metrics, the admin section will have seperate, Advertises will have seperate, etc. So basically the goal is to have 1 framework in place for all Analytics, which will be custom user to user and even use that for the system analytic needs also. It will include data analytics as there will be user ratings/reviews to perfomr data mining on for businesses, USers will have basic reporting on their needs (like friend demographics, filter by different preferences, etc).

System is being developed in cakePhp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting tool. With myDBR you can easily create reports and include them into your application. myDBR is also written in PHP and can easily be integrated into any existing web-application via Single-Sign On authentication.